# Leading Wildcard Multiword in Solr Not working

Tags: solrj, solr4

I am trying for multiword leading wild card search in solr.

Ex: *oogle - works for me

*oogle maps - doesn't work for me

Can you provide me the valid query and solution for this issue,

**schema.xml**

```
<field name="abc_name" type="text_app" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="abc_address" type="text_app" indexed="true" stored="true"/>   <field name="abc_notes" type="text_app" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="abc_allSearchFields" type="text_app" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>   

<copyField source="abc_*" dest="abc_allSearchFields"/> 

<fieldType name="text_app" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

In the query,

1. q=abc_allSearchFields:"google maps" ---- Will fetch all results that match **google maps** together. Works for me.
2. q=abc_allSearchFields:*ogle ---> will fetch all records that has words that end with **ogle**. Works for me.
3. q=abc_allSearchFields:"*gle maps" ---- This is fetching all record words that end with gle and maps separately. But my requirement is to get all records containing "*gle maps" **together only** like "google maps".

Can some one help me with the solution for the 3rd case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a [ReversedWildcardFilterFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_6_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/analysis/ReversedWildcardFilterFactory.html) in the index analyzer chain of the corresponding field type to make that work.

But beware of this issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3193

Comment: Can you provide some example of the implementation of the reversedWildcard in solrj?

Comment: You do not need to do something in Solj. It just makes leading wildcards work. But note that you have to re-index!